# Bitrate data on RTMP stream

Tags: audio, video, metadata, bitrate, rtmp

When I check the RTMP stream with ffprobe and rtmpdump, Some streams are show the audio and video bitrate data. But some others not. 
What cause this happen?
And, I'm using the wowza as the origin server.
Can I put the bitrate metadata to the RTMP stream with Wowza?